# download.file in R using wget

Tags: r, wget

The webpage I am trying to access downloads an attachment but header status is always 500 which I have checked through postman.

I am using `download.file` with `wget` method in R to download that file but it stops and doesn't download since the header status is 500. How can I manage to download this file irrespective of the header status?

When I access this link in browser, the file is downloaded just fine.

Edit:

Here's how I use download.file function in R:

```
  download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget");
```

I tried to pass the extra argument like:

```
 download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget", extra =getOption("content-on-error"));
```

and

```
  download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget", extra =getOption("--content-on-error=0"));
```

but it doesn't work

Here :

`get(url)` points to the link:(have replaced actual key with **KEY**)

```
https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=__KEY__&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&start_date=01-01-2013&end_date=10-05-2016&format=csv&currency=USD
```

message on trying to connect:

```
Resolving app.adroll.com... 52.11.56.178, 52.89.249.63
Connecting to app.adroll.com|52.11.56.178|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-10-06 16:22:21 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```