# pass options to wget in download.file

Tags: r

I have this wget command:

```
wget -x --load-cookies /home/rstudio/cookies.txt  'https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD' --debug -P /home/rstudio -O /home/rstudio/adrollCampaigns
```

I need to convert it to `download.file` in R with `wget` method but not able to understand how to pass options to it.

```
 download.file(get(url), destfile=tmpFile, method = "wget", extra =getOption( ));
```

Please suggest how to use getOption here to pass same arguments as in wget command.

Comment: Is there any reason you specifically need to use `download.file`? You might be well served passing the command string via `system`.

Comment: If you can generate a "Copy as cURL" string you can try using `curlconverter` to generate a compatible `httr` request.  However, the `extra` parameter is just a character string of options as they would appear on the command line (one string, not a multiple string vector). But, you may run into the same issue as [this poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896694/download-file-in-r-using-wget).